# How to add dynamic cells into this code?

Tags: itext

I have this code to generate a table from mysqlite with itext, but the number of cells is static(only 2) no matter the records I have in the database, can you please help me get dynamic cells depending on the number of records ?Thank you very much

```
// Table
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    // Header
    PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("groups"));
    PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("machines"));
    table.addCell(cell1);
    table.addCell(cell2);
    // Data
    db = new Database(FirstActivity.this);
    Cursor c = db.getGroupsNamesMachines();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String group = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("groupname"));
            cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(group));
            table.addCell(cell1);
            String machine = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("machinename"));
            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(machine));
            table.addCell(cell2);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    document.add(table);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing cells with columns, and fields with rows.

The number of fields is known up-front. If you have `"SELECT groupname, machinename FROM groupmachines;"`, you know that each record will have two fields, hence you need 2 columns. If you have `"SELECT groupid, groupname, machinename FROM groupmachines;"`, you will need 3 columns, and so on.

The number of records isn't known up-front. You perform a query, and the `Cursor` keeps on giving you data as long there are records left. That's not a problem: just add one row to the table for each record. Adding a row happens implicitly in iText: you have a complete row as soon as you've added as many cells as there are columns.

Once you add the table to the document, the rows will be distributed over different pages if the table doesn't fit a single page.

Comment: So why it only shows the two first groups, and the other groups dont show on the table?

Comment: Your allegation is false. Take a look at the [UnitedStates](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/render-data-table#675-unitedstates.java) example. There are 50 states in the database, hence there are 50 body rows in  [united_states.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/tables/cmp_united_states.pdf). Add `System.out.println("group")` inside your loop, and you'll discover that the awkward way you loop over the `Cursor` is the culprit: you only look at two rows.

Comment: So can you fix my code please, if is not asking much?

Comment: No, because I never worked with `Cursor`; I always work with `ResultSet`. I don't understand why you're using `moveToFirst()` and `c.moveToNext()`.

Comment: Bottom line: if the table generated by iText only shows two data rows, there is no other explanation than that there are only two records returned by the database query.

Comment: this is my query: select group.groupname group_concat(machine.machinename,' , ') as namemachine from machine inner join group on machine.id_group = group.idGruop group by group.groupname can you please exemplify using ResultSet and then using that in itext please? I really need this to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141252/discussion-between-jose-and-bruno-lowagie).

Comment: It's midnight! Why would I chat while I'm in bed trying to sleep? Just debug your code. Telling people what your query looks like won't help as they don't have access to your database. Please be more professional.

Comment: How did you solve the problem? (Als in bed, and I had a couple of cocktails, so I am not very professional at the moment)